# css keyframe animation won't stop on last frame

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a 29 frame animation of a tree growing and I want it to stop on the last frame, (when it's fully grown.) I've been trying to look for a solution to have it stop on the last frame, but nothing seems to be affecting it. I can either get it to loop, or just reset to the first frame.

Can someone please explain to me why this animation keeps just resetting back to the first frame? Thanks so much!

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
.tree-right {
-webkit-animation: treeright 2.0s steps(29);
-moz-animation: treeright 2.0s steps(29);
-ms-animation: treeright 2.0s steps(29);
-o-animation: treeright 2.0s steps(29);
animation: treeright 2.0s steps(29);
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes treeright {
from { background-position:    0px; }
to { background-position: -5310px; }

}

@-moz-keyframes treeright {
from { background-position:    0px; }
to { background-position: -5310px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes treeright {
from { background-position:    0px; }
to { background-position: -5310px; }
}

@-o-keyframes treeright {
from { background-position:    0px; }
to { background-position: -5310px; }
}

@keyframes treeright {
from { background-position:    0px; }
to { background-position: -5310px; }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a live example we can view? Such as a codepen or jsfiddle? Difficult to help if we can't see the behavior.

Comment: Just a guess, but try moving 'animation-fill-mode: forwards;' to 'animation: treeright 2.0s steps(29) forwards;' and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here last frame you mean is background-position: -5310px;  you can stop in the same position by using -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;.

For more clarification. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `steps(28)` if you have 29 frames and for the background-position offset use `28*(height of your frames)`. [I just figured this out.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1025696) Also, the background-position property requires two values. You always have to specify both X and Y offsets, I believe.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/267Lx/)

Answer (score 0):

Without more info its hard to gauge what the root issue is, however have you tried setting the iteration limit to 1?

```
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
       -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
         -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

Comment: yes, i've tried it, and it's not effecting it at all

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is working ok.

I have prepared ths fiddle,

[http://jsfiddle.net/vals/REkbW/]

copying your code, and changing just the animation from background-position to background-color to check it easily (and because I don't have your background image); it works ok for me

Comment: This works with background-color but not with background-position, it seems. Tested in FF30, Chrome 35 and Opera 12.16. Trying to make this work for a project.

Comment: @hawk Can you show your code ?

Comment: Yep, see the test case at my Bugzilla ticket: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1025696

Comment: Nevermind. I think I got to the bottom of this. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304821/css-keyframe-animation-wont-stop-on-last-frame/24235618#24235618). Friggin' off-by-one errors!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this sometimes only works for items which are position:absolute

Hope this works for you!